# if else conditions with table input field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery code table to display the error messages after some comparison via `if else` condition with fixed values, but it's not working, I want `if else` condition with it's table input typed values.

Can anyone please check this & let me know what is wrong? Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .widtot, .perm, .tottot, .vol, .tot, .vols, .widths, .depths, .heights, .acts, .heitot').prop('readonly', true);
    var $tblrows = $("#tblProducts tbody tr");
    $tblrows.each(function (index) {
    var $tblrow = $(this);
    $tblrow.find('.width, .carton, .depth, .height, .act, .tot, .vol, .perm').on('change', function () {
    var height = $tblrow.find("[name=height][type=number][min=0]").val();
    var subCalc  =  parseFloat(height);
    if (!isNaN(subCalc)) {
    $tblrow.find('.calcheight').val(subCalc.toFixed(5));
    var calcTotal = 0;
    $(".calcheight").each(function () {
    var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
    calcTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
    });
    $('.heitot').val(calcTotal.toFixed(5));
    }
    }); 
    }); 
    });
</script>

<table id="tblProducts">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var sp = $('#sellingprice').val() | 0;
    if (sp >= 2.38) {
        <?php echo "error with 20 STD and error with 40 STD"; ?>
    }
    else if (sp >= 2.69){
        <?php echo "error with 40 HC"; ?>
    }
   else 
   {
  <?php echo ""; ?>
  }
</script>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="First One" name="pnm" style="width:120px" /></td>

    <td><input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" id="sellingprice" class="height" value="0" name="height" min="0" maxlength="5" style="width:100px"/></td>       
    <td><input type="number" class="calcheight" value="" name="calcheight" style="width:100px" readonly/></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Second One" name="pnm" style="width:120px" /></td>

    <td><input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" id="sellingprice" class="height" value="0" name="height" min="0" maxlength="5" style="width:100px"/></td>
     <td><input type="number" class="calcheight" value="" name="calcheight" style="width:100px" readonly/></td> 
    </tr>
 </tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="heitot" value="" name="" style="width:100px" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have PHP code running within a JavaScript function, which unless you're doing something wacky server-side, isn't going to do what you want. Instead, change those `<?php echo ... ?>` lines to `alert(...)`, at least to test it out.

Second, you have:

```
var sp = $('#sellingprice').val() | 0;
```

You're going to want to change that single `|` or a double `||`. Single `|` is binary "or", not logical "or":

```
var sp = $('#sellingprice').val() || 0;
```

Comment: ok but what would i have to use in place of var sp = $('#sellingprice').val() | 0;

Comment: I updated the answer showing what you should change it to.

Comment: i did that changes that you suggest me but no its not working. its not showing me any error messages please check again Regards Inder –

Comment: Give this a try: [https://jsfiddle.net/LvzjLp06/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/LvzjLp06/3/).

Comment: sir it gaves me error but its showing me alertbox after onclick on button it shoud display error without button & the concept is if you enter  the value in the first row column 2nd then it should display errorr but next after to the table near row 1st & same for 2nd & so on  sir you are closer my answer please check again & reply me with demo same as last reply with that i can easily check  thanks Inder

Comment: Give this a try: [https://jsfiddle.net/LvzjLp06/13/](https://jsfiddle.net/LvzjLp06/13/). You have a few errors in your original code that I don't know how to account for. (For example, you shouldn't ever have two elements with the same `id`.) But the fiddle above should get you closer to where you want to be. Good luck!

Comment: sir i checked your latest changes its working but little mistake & that is if i enter 5 in the first row then it should gave me 2 errors "error with 20 STD and error with 40 STD" and  "error with 40 HC" bcz the 5 value is greater than both conditions it should display error messages according to the conditions please check little more & reply me sir thanks Regards Inder

Comment: sir thank you so much its working. thank you for your reply for your time to help me . thank you so much